# Python: access dicts inside list, better way

Tags: python, optimization, dictionary

I have following list,

```
admin_extra = [
                {
                   'name': 'nikhil',
                    'passkey': 'nikhilpasskey' 
                },

                {
                    'name': 'mac',
                    'passkey': 'macpasskey' 
                },
             ]
```

how to get dicts inside list in better way?
and print error if no match found?

I have done with

```
name = 'nikhil'

flag = 0

for admin in admin_extra:
    if admin['name'] == name:
        passkey = admin[passkey]
        flag = 1
        return passkey

if not flag:
    print "not found"
```

Also i wish to eliminate flag logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to put the code inside a function (as it looks like you have done by the presence of `return`:

```
def get_passkey(admin_extra, name):
    for admin in admin_extra:
        if admin['name'] == name:
            passkey = admin[passkey]
        return passkey
    # this will not happen if we have left the function due to returning the passkey
    return None     # We did not find a passkey
```

Another way would be using the [break](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement) statement:

```
name = 'nikhil'
passkey = ''

for admin in admin_extra:
    if admin['name'] == name:
        passkey = admin[passkey]
        print passkey
        break
else:
    print "not found"
```

Other (partially tongue-in-cheek) suggestion: use [classes](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Example code:

```
admins = AdminList(Admin("Nikhil", "nikhilpasskey"), Admin("Mac", "macpasskey"))
pass = admins["Nikhil"].passkey
```

Comment: Your second example is invalid. The else-block is completely misplaced. I guess you wanted to check whether passkey is still `''`.

Comment: Nope, Python's `else` statement works for `for` loops! The code in the block is called if, and only if the loop *isn't* broken out of.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious approach would be to use a `break` statement.

```
passkey = None

for admin in admin_extra:
    if admin['name'] == name:
        passkey = admin["passkey"]
        break

if passkey is None:
    print "not found"
```

Alternatively use list comprehension:

```
matching_admin_extras = [ae for ae in admin_extra if ae["name"] == name]

if len(matching_admin_extras)==0:
    print "not found"
elif len(matching_admin_extras)>1:
    print "multiple matches"
else:
    print matching_admin_extras[0]["passkey"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
name = 'nikhil'

try:
    passkey = [admin['passkey'] for admin in admin_extra if admin['name'] == name][0]
except IndexError:
    print "No passkey found for", name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filtered=[item['passkey'] for item in admin_extra if item['name'] == name]
return filtered[0] if filtered else 'not found'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
ae_names = [ae['name'] for ae in admin_extra]

if name not in ae_names:
    print "not found"
```

Comment: OP wants to get the passkey, this does not achieve that.

Comment: :) Thanks Ludo. as per user2387370 i also want to get passkey

Comment: Oops, I missed that. (BTW: I would advice against putting `return` statements inside loops.) Go with @ThorstenKranz solution.